useServerSeoMeta not setting head-tags on server
Using Nuxt3 and useServerSeoMeta and/or useSeoMeta, I would assume this would generate correct HTML on server side but it does not. I just took the example straight from Nuxt documentation, and on client side it looks perfect, but on server side when viewing source (ctrl + u), it takes the value from app.head.meta.title in the nuxt.config.js and is not overridden.
If I remove the property from nuxt.config.js, it generates some arbitrary value based on the path used but still not getting the value from my useSeoMeta.
useServerSeoMeta({
  title: 'My Amazing Site',
  ogTitle: 'My Amazing Site',
  description: 'This is my amazing site, let me tell you all about it.',
  ogDescription: 'This is my amazing site, let me tell you all about it.',
  ogImage: 'https://example.com/image.png',
  twitterCard: 'summary_large_image',
})


Same problem.
While definePageMeta is for server-side rendering, useServerSeoMeta is for client-side. Its name is misleading.
I think it's a bug of Nuxt3.
